# IndexOf() vs Replace() and zero-width non-joiner

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-4.7.2

Why does `IndexOf()` ignore the zero-width non-joiner `char`, but `Replace()` doesn't:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string zeroWidthNonJoiner = "\u200C";

        string str = $"ab{zeroWidthNonJoiner}cd";

        int index = str.IndexOf("bc"); //index = 1 (does ignore the zeroWidthNonJoiner)

        string replaced = str.Replace("bc", "BC"); //replaced = "abcd" (does NOT ignore the zeroWidthNonJoiner)

    }
}
```

Comment: The doc for `Replace` specifies: "This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue.", whereas for `IndexOf`: "This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture."

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html). See the [Matching multiple characters](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#matching-multiple-characters) section.

Comment: This is a known issue, mostly because users copy stuff from html pages and paste in all kinds of formatting artifacts (but also text files that use these format-control characters when a higher-level protocol is not available). If you need to accept input that comes from *the wild*, a *cleaner* proc that strips ranges of unicode chars (and standard control codes) is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

`String.Replace(String,string)`'s [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) doco states:

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue.

`String.IndexOf`'s [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,cf9e6bfe83442551,references) shows that it uses `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`

```
public int IndexOf(String value) {
            return IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
        }
```

---

## What to do

In .NET core you can do it with `InvariantCulture`

```
string replaced = str.Replace("bc", "BC", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: +1, or `int index = str.IndexOf("bc", StringComparison.Ordinal)` to see the opposite effect on `IndexOf`

Comment: Yeah, `IndexOf` by default uses `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`